# COVID-19 contact tracing API stats?

Tags: google-play-services

Is there a way to see how many unique contact tracing IDs my phone has registered via BLE?

Answer (score 3):

**Nope.**

As part of the joint Apple/Google initiative, a great deal of emphasis is placed on the privacy of the data. Authorized Covid-19 Exposure Notification Apps are the only ones that can use the API. Even the Apps themselves have no way of asking such a question.

On Android the Google Play Service is the one sending out identifiers and recording nearby identifiers.

From **Architecture** section of the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/android/exposure-notifications/exposure-notifications-api

Google Play Services:

- Manages daily random keys
- Manages Bluetooth broadcast and collection
- Identifies whether the user was in close contact with a confirmed case
- Presents permission requests to user for scanning/reading beacons and submitting user keys on diagnosis.

The Exposure Notification App submits a set of suspect identifiers (presumably from a secure medical source, i.e. those who have tested positive) into the Google Play Service API and that returns a risk score on that identifier.

You as a user won't know anything beyond what the app will tell you and the app is limited to the data in `ExposureSummary`/`ExposureInformation` or `ExposureWindow` as found in the [Exposure Notification API data structure documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/exposure-notifications/exposure-notifications-api#data-structures). Wether all of the detail in available in exposure datasets is presented to the user is determined by the App authors presumably in conjunction with local health authorities.